# How do i use ldapmodify for the first time when i do not know any user or password for authentication?

Tags: openldap

I am unable to apply changes using ldapmodify for the first time after installing openldap on my rhel7 server.

I have installed openldap from the scratch. Now i want to modify the olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif to put my own olcSuffix,olcRootDN and olcRootPW.

I have generated the encrypted password with ldappasswd and put that along with other two parameters to .ldif file.

Now when, i try to apply these changes to my ldap setup using following command

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL  -H ldapi:/// -f db.ldif
```

i get the error as

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
```

further if i wish to use -D to bind with the default user -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" it needs a password. i do not know what username password combination i should use to run my first ever ldapmodify on this newly installed openldap.

Your help is much appreciated.

Best regards,
Amit Joshi

Comment: Do you have option `SASL_NOCANON on` in your _ldap.conf_?

Comment: yes. it is set like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting an OpenLDAP bug (see [ITS#8998](https://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi?findid=8998)).

The solution is to either

1. unset option `SASL_NOCANON` in ldap.conf or
2. specify the full path in the LDAPI URI (with URL-quoting of slashes).

The first option might be easier but might affect binding with SASL/GSSAPI (Kerberos).